# Convert String List to URI List

Tags: c#, .net

I have `List<String>` which contains URLS.
How can i convert it to URI List?

The string list is populated like this

```
foreach (Match m in linkParser.Matches(rawString))
{
    urllist.Add(rawString);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not take your code further and do

```
foreach (Match m in linkParser.Matches(rawString))
{
    urllist.Add(new Uri(rawString));
}
```

Convert them in one step?

Answer (score 2):

You can use linq:

```
var links = urllist.Select(s => new Uri(s)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

A one-line `ForEach` would also be possible.

```
List<Uri> Urilist = new List<Uri>();
urllist.ForEach(s => Urilist.Add(new Uri(s)));
```

But i would prefer the LINQ solution in the other answer.